# Android emulators don't start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Since yesterday, my android studio emulators don't start. It was just after i updated Android Studio Library, i don't know if it is just a coïncidence.

What happens when i press start is:

- The emulator command is executed
- I see emulator.exe process in windows task manager, but no window is opened

Before that, the emulators started just fine, i had no problems, so it shouldn't be hardware issues.

I tried to launch it from the command line, to see if there were errors, but there's nothing. I also checked android studio's logs but still nothing... I also reinstalled completely android studio with no effects. I also tried to let it run for awhile but nothing appears.

Does anyone have a clue about what could cause this ?

EDIT :
It was a known issue (GPU related) of the SDK Tools 25.1.1 , it has been updated about 5 days later and now it works perfectly.

Comment: android sdk tools must have been updated, Recreate the emulator and try.

Comment: I have the latest verison of Android SDK Tools, and yes i've tried creating a new emulator. It still won't start.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.

Removing **C:Windows\System32\Wbem** from system **PATH** variable helps me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36650430/1901621