# Emulator not working in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-studio-2.0

I am using Android Studio 2.0 Stable version. Whenever I click on the play button on the device to run it shows starting AVD progress in android studio and after completing it's progress nothing happened.The app window remains as it shown in screenshot and the emulator doesn't start. I can't find a solution for this issue. I have already tried many solutions which I found on the internet, changing HAXM version android SDK update, changed target API's. But nothing works.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try edit AVD Settings -> Emulated Performance -> Graphics. Set Software - GLES 2.0.

Comment: Yeah..its working..but emulator is too slow...i am using HAXM x86

Comment: Thanks! great help!!

Answer (score 2):

Installing the Android Emulator (marked in to the image) solved my problem. If still you face face problem install API simulator and DHU emulator too. But only AE will solve the issue I guess.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue.

Windows 7 Professional SP1. Installed Android Studio 2.0, new HAXM ver 6.0.1 and updated to all new components like SDK tools 25.1.1.

When started - emulator do not shows up any window. 'emulator.exe' runs in the task manager and eats 25% of CPU.

Deleted all AVDs, re-created new; used AVD Manager directly; used ARM/Atom images (with/without HAXM); tried AVD with different API level - nothing helps.

Reverting to Android SDK Tools 24.4.2 helps - I can run emulator as usual - so, looks this is not the issue of new HAXM 6.0.1.

After day fighting finally got resolution:

I have removed **C:Windows\System32\Wbem** from system **PATH** variable.

Comment: i am not able to find C:Windows\System32\Wbem this path variable my environmental variables

Comment: My PATH variable is very long. Many programs at install adds there something. At some point it starts conflicting. What i did initially is just removed almost everything from **PATH**. I have created 'run.bat' file with 2 lines like followed:

'set path C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS'

'D:\Java\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus5_API_N -verbose'
Then emulator started showing window. Later i have incrementally added parts of **PATH** back and realized that for my setup problematic was 'C:Windows\System32\Wbem'. In your case can be something else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just created the AVD with 768 MB RAM and it did run fine!

Comment: I keep trying to do the same but the Virtual Device manager just bumps it up to 1GB on me automatically. Is the same happening to you?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues as you.  I upgraded Android Studio to 2.0 stable which also updated the Android SDK.

I believe this issue is more of an Android SDK issue since using the SDK's AVD Manager directly I can replicate the issue.

As another data point, I've also modified the Virtual Device to only use 768MB RAM, to no effect.  The Task manager shows the emulator using 2 threads and 13% CPU no matter how long I leave it running, but no window ever appears.  I've tried with and without the HAXM.  My virtual devices are running API level 21 (x86_64) and 19 (x86).

I've also reinstalled both Android Studio and the Android SDK without any affect.  It could be a configuration issue due to the 2.0 and SDK upgrade, a broken SDK release, or something else entirely.

**Reverting to Android SDK 24.4.1 allows the Emulator to start working again,** but without the 25.1.1 functionality.

Comment: What is the solution for this if we want the new emulator to work in android studio 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

1. open `cmd`
2. type `set` and check if you can see `C:\Windows\System32\Wbem` in `PATH` variable
3. go to Control Panel -> System (on the left)->Advanced system settings -> (button at the bottom) Environment variables

   Either in user variables (or more likely system variables) in variable `PATH` remove

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem (or  C:\Windows\System32\Wbem)
   ```
4. restart studio

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. I checked SDK manager, turns out emulator has not been installed. After it's been installed, emulator start showing